# it support analyst Annual Development Review Preparation Form

Tags: career-development

I need help with my Annual Development Review Preparation Form

The first question asks how I, within my role, contribute to the company.

The list below is what I do daily, but I'm not sure how to put that down in words.

- installing and configuring computer hardware operating systems and applications;
- monitoring and maintaining computer systems and networks;
- talking staff or clients through a series of actions, either face to face or over the telephone to help set up systems or resolve issues;
- troubleshooting system and network problems and diagnosing and solving hardware or software faults;
- replacing parts as required;
- providing support, including procedural documentation and relevant
  reports;
- following diagrams and written instructions to repair a fault or set
  up a system;
- supporting the roll-out of new applications;
- setting up new users' accounts and profiles and dealing with password
  issues;
- responding within agreed time limits to call-outs;
- working continuously on a task until completion (or referral to third
  parties, if appropriate);
- prioritising and managing many open cases at one time;
- rapidly establishing a good working relationship with customers and
  other professionals, e.g., software developers;
- testing and evaluating new technology;

Comment: Do you support company staff, external clients or both?

Comment: Internal staff company staff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't focus on the stuff they already know. That's a waste of space, and a waste of an opportunity. 
Assume your manager gets fired right after the review, and replaced with someone new to the company. Your company files are what give the replacement the first impression of you. They know your job description, they need to know what else you do.

First off, start with a paragraph on soft skills. Describe how you help the company, with your attitude. The following points can be worked into that paragraph:

- working continuously on a task until completion (or referral to third parties, if appropriate
- rapidly establishing a good working relationship with customers and other professionals, e.g., software developers;

If you often make suggestions on how to improve processes, or improve them yourself, mention that too. If you solve conflicts between coworkers also mention that.

Then mention big projects and special achievements in the second paragraph, if there were any. Such as "Handled the rollout of the XYZ framework", "Resolved the David Eastwood emergency" (you'd need to give a little more detail than that, of course).

Finally, make a list of the day to day tasks. Keep this short, or you risk that people won't read it. If management was really only interested in the technical day to day tasks, they will easily spot the list and not be bothered by the 2 paragraphs above it. They might need that list for various things, one among them being to hire a replacement if you get fired, or promoted.